# Cassandra clustering columns and performance

Tags: cassandra, datastax

So I have a materialized view defined as follows (changed the name a bit):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MYVIEW AS
    SELECT *
    FROM XXXX
    WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND process_on_date_time IS NOT NULL AND poller_processing_status IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (poller_processing_status, process_on_date_time, id)
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (process_on_date_time ASC, id ASC)
...
```

Based off of the definition, the data would be sorted by the PROCESS_ON_DATE_TIME column in ASC order (oldest first).

Now I have a query that runs as follows:

```
SELECT JSON * FROM MYVIEW
WHERE poller_processing_status='PENDING'
AND process_on_date_time<=1548775105000  LIMIT 250  ;
```

There are over 250 rows that match, so 250 are returned. Running this from CQLSH, it fetches 3 times - the first two fetch 100 rows and the last one fetches 50 rows. I enabled tracing via CQLSH with consistency LOCAL_ONE. Now of the first two fetches - they do EXACTLY the same steps, in the same order, same sstables, etc. One of them always takes 2 SECONDS, the other 8 ms. I can't for the life of me figure out why one takes over 2 seconds. The slow guy stalls on "Merged data from memtables and 3 sstables" (but again, but the first two fetches do EXACTLY the same thing, but one is slow and the next is fast - same merged sstables).

Move on to step 2. I thought, ok, we have a clustering column so it's sorted. What if I add an ORDER BY clause to sort the results. So I ran this:

```
SELECT JSON * FROM sop_cas.notification_by_status_ptd_mv
WHERE poller_processing_status='PENDING'
AND process_on_date_time<=1548775105000
ORDER BY process_on_date_time ASC LIMIT 250  ;
```

So basically the exact same query, specifying an order in the same order as the sorted data (clustering columns). Results? Same - over 2 seconds to complete. No improvement. Bummer.

Now one last test. I changed the sort in my query from ASC to DESC and give it a try. Results? Every time the query responds in less than 10 milliseconds. Huh???? This is what I'm trying to achieve - but why does the REVERSE sort run well?

I would figure that as I'm asking for records OLDER than something, an ASC sort would be best because the oldest records would be first and immediately grabbed. The other route, DESC, I would have newer records first and thus would have to skip over a bunch to find the first record older than my timestamp and then grab the next 250. Can anyone help me with this logic? Why does a DESC ORDER BY respond well while the ASC does not.

Using DSE 5.1.9

Thanks in advance.

-Jim

Comment: How large is the `PENDING` partition? A request should never take 2 seconds, thats most likely from the heap being overwhelmed and a stop the world GC which is common issue with wide partitions. Anything in system log or gc log?

Comment: I didn't see any errors in any cassandra logs. I also created a separate mat view that has the desc sort for the process_on_date_time, and it works just like the ORDER BY DESC does. There's definitely something up with the order, but I can't put a finger on it. For the slow sort, it's every time I run it. There's a whopping 3 sstables for this table right now (maybe 100MB). If it was a partition issue, it would be slow for all queries no matter the sort as we're specifying the same partition key every time.